# Use mapped() in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

What is mapped and how use this in odoo 9?

Any simple example?

On oficial page stay:

```
# returns a list of names
records.mapped('name')

# returns a recordset of partners
record.mapped('partner_id')

# returns the union of all partner banks, with duplicates removed
record.mapped('partner_id.bank_ids')
```

Comment: This example seams clear. If not, you should have a good grasp of what is a recordset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically it is a convenience method to return recordsets (lists of objects or values). Lets say you wanted a list of all partners email addresses matching a specific domain. You could easily accomplish this like so.

```
domain = [('email','not in',[False,None])]
records = self.env['res.partner'].search(domain)
email_list = records.mapped('email')

print(email_list)
>>> [u'john@gmail.com',u'suzy@gmail.com',u'bob@hotmail.com']
```

This way you do not need to do this

```
email_list = []
domain = [('email','not in',[False,None])]
for rec in self.env['res.partner'].search(domain):
    if rec.email: 
        email_list.append(rec.email) 
print(email_list)
>>> [u'john@gmail.com',u'suzy@gmail.com',u'bob@hotmail.com']
```

In the above example odoo would have iterated through all of the records and returned the email from each record in the form of a list.

So rather than looping through all records to obtain the same field from each record you can use mapped.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I still do not understand what is advantages of this!